# Xamarin.Forms Azure DocumentDb Exception

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-cosmosdb

I am using latest version of Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core (1.3.1.0) but keep getting an exception when trying to connect:

Example:

I create a Client Connection:

```
if (Client == null)
{
    Client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(AppConstants.SUBSCRIPTION_URL),
    AppConstants.PRIMARY_KEY);              
}
```

And I try to query some data:

```
public async Task<List<Config>> GetAll()
{
    var configs = new List<Config>();
    var queryOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 };
    var settings = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<Config>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(AppConstants.COSMOS_DATABASE, COLLECTION_ID), queryOptions).AsDocumentQuery();
    if (settings != null)
    {
        while(settings.HasMoreResults)
        {
            configs.AddRange(await settings.ExecuteNextAsync<Config>());
        }

    }
    return configs;
}
```

And I get this error, even tough Settings is not null:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

[image]

At first I thought its todo with the Client not being open so I tried adding:

```
await Client.OpenAsync();
```

But this has the same issue.  Now running this same code in Asp.Net using the Web Client Nuget, The code runs perfectly.

Any ideas if recent changes to Xamarin or DocumentDB could be the cause or am I missing something else please?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you also please post the code. I can't see the end of the CreateDocumentQuery line, is it an AsDocumentQuery() or a .ToList()?

Comment: Hey Adam, Thanks for the reply mate, I think I just nailed it. I have added the code regardless, But I found it was the linking.  To Get the local SQLite working I added some assemblies to skip and one of them was the System.Runtime.Serialization.  Once I took thsi out, Bang problem solved.  After a whole day of scratching my head and checking my sanity..